# Add a dropdown menu next to every links inside a div

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to put a mini dropdown menu after EVERY link inside a `.Post-body div.`, but I can't find the right way.

My example div:
https://jsfiddle.net/0zc4pbqh/2/

```
<div class="Post-body"><p><a href="https://www.netflix.com/" rel=" nofollow ugc">https://www.netflix.com/</a> lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum <a href="https://www.netflix.com/" rel=" nofollow ugc">https://www.netflix.com/</a>  lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p></div>
```

What is the correct way to do this?

p.s. I want to fill this dropdown with a website screenshot (from an api).

Answer (score 1):

try this although its has some bug when you go bottom of page or right end which can be tweaked

```js
const pbody = document.querySelector(".Post-body"),
        ancS = pbody.querySelectorAll("a"),
        menu = pbody.querySelector(".menu")

ancS.forEach(each=>{
    each.addEventListener("mouseover",e=>{
        let cords = each.getClientRects()[0],
            x = cords.x, 
            y = cords.y,
            offset = {x:0,y:40}
        menu.style.display="block"
        menu.style.left = (x + offset.x) + "px"
        menu.style.top = (y + offset.y) + "px"

        // on menu show (each is current anchor tag)
        menu.innerHTML = "you are hovering over :" + each.href
    })
    each.addEventListener("mouseout",e=>{menu.style.display="none"})
})
```

```css
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background:white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px black;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Post-body">
    <p><a href="https://www.netflix.com/" rel=" nofollow ugc">https://www.netflix.com/</a>
        sdfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsf
        sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd
        sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf
        sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd
        sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf
        sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd
        sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf
        sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"
            rel=" nofollow ugc">https://www.youtube.com/</a> dsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf
        sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfddsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfddsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd
        sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfddsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf
        sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfddsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfddsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd
        sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfddsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf
        sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfddsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd sfdsfdsfdsf sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd</p>
        <div class="menu">
            this is menu
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i get uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous>

Comment: its running fine in my opera are you serious ?

Comment: yes i can see your code works fine into the snippet, but into my app i get this error, thanks for your help btw, maybe i can't use .style

Comment: is it possible to do the same but with separate css?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>  
function favTutorial() {  
var mylist = document.getElementById("myList");  
document.getElementById("favourite").value = mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].text;  
}  
</script>  
<div class="Post-body"><p><a href="https://www.netflix.com/" rel=" nofollow ugc">https://www.netflix.com/
<select id = "myList" onchange = "favTutorial()" >  
<option> ---Choose tutorial--- </option>  
<option> w3schools </option>  
<option> Javatpoint </option>  
<option> tutorialspoint </option>  
<option> geeksforgeeks </option>  
</select>  </a>
```

You need to create a select with specific ID and use that ID to display your dropdown list. You can use class also (document.getElementsByClassName) if the content of all the  dropdowns are same.

https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-create-dropdown-list-using-javascript

Please  refer to this link also.

Comment: I couldn't understand your code as there was no javascript code and no select tag was used.

Comment: and is not placed after each link, so how can i place this near every link in the div?

Comment: put select inside <a> tag starting and  closing or just after it as per your need.